# Blueimp's jquery fileupload of large files fails when chuncked

Tags: jquery, file-upload, servicestack, durandal

Using the latest version of blueimp's jquery fileupload in a durandal web app. I've used an older version (4.x) in another asp.net project and it works well there. The backend is servicestack.

I can upload files up to 3MB with no problem (`multipart=true`) while sending additional form data, great!  When I set a `maxChunkSize` to 1MB and attempt to send a 2MB file (no problem with no `maxChunkSize=0`) the `fileuploadchunkbeforesend` and `fileuploadchunksend` events fire, then I get `fileuploadchunkfail` with no error message.  The server is never hit in this case and the headers (from `fileuploadchunkfail`) show bytes 0-1MB of 2MB, which is all correct.

In order to support sending files greater than 3MB it seems I need to chunk the files.

```
        $('#fileUpload').fileupload({
            url: webservice + "UploadFile",
            dataType: 'json',
            multipart: true,
            maxChunkSize: 1048576,
            autoUpload: false,
            formData: [{ name: 'a', value: 1 }, { name: 'b', value: 2 }],
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            disableImageResize: true,
            previewMaxWidth: 465,
            previewMaxHeight: 465,
            previewCrop: false
        });
```

I'm willing to look at other upload solutions if I can't get this one to work.  The project seems to have an older version of dropzone.js included which it does not use.
I've gone through the javascript of jquery-fileuploader but can't figure out why its failing, I'm sure I could eventually but its a case of diminishing returns.

Any ideas on where to look for the cause of this error (in the jquery-uploader.js files) or any suggestion on a better solution?

I just need to reliably upload arbitrarily large image files, with a progress bar and preview. (I can do the preview myself if need be).

Comment: I eventually gave up and went with dropzone.js.  After some minor customization (the code is pretty straight-forward) I can upload multiple, arbitrarily large files simultaneously with no problems.